# implement JavaScript callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm a beginner in **Javascript** I have an api which I need to execute asynchronously or I need a request to be executed only after the previous one is completed.

Researching I found that with **Callback** it is possible to do this, however I cannot implement it in my script.

Below is my **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="loading" lang="en" data-textdirection="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="description" content="Chameleon Admin is a modern Bootstrap 4 webapp &amp; admin dashboard html template with a large number of components, elegant design, clean and organized code.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="admin template, Chameleon admin template, dashboard template, gradient admin template, responsive admin template, webapp, eCommerce dashboard, analytic dashboard">
    <meta name="author" content="Niklausec">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../../theme-assets/images/ico/apple-icon-120.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="theme-assets/images/logo/logo.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i%7CComfortaa:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/fonts/line-awesome/1.1/css/line-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="vertical-layout vertical-menu 2-columns menu-expanded fixed-navbar" style="background: #0f1321;" data-open="click" data-menu="vertical-menu" data-color="bg-chartbg" data-col="2-columns">


<div class="container mt-4" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">

    <div class="text-center mb-3">
  

    <div class="text-center ">
        <h1 class="text-light"><b></b>  </h1>
        <div class="text-center ">
    </div>
        <textarea class="form-control bg-dark text-light" style="resize: none;text-align: center;margin: auto;" rows="12" id="lista" placeholder="Informe sua lista"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <center>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" id="testar" onclick="enviar()">INICIAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" id="parar" disabled="true">PARAR</button>
            <a href="../../" class="btn btn-primary btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1">VOLTAR</a>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="badge badge-success badge-pill" style="padding: 10px 10px;margin: 5px;">
            <i class="la la-check"></i>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Aprovados</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;" id="cLive">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="badge badge-danger badge-pill" style="padding: 10px 10px;margin: 5px;">
            <i class="la la-close"></i>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Reprovados</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;" id="cDie">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="padding: 10px 10px;margin: 5px;">
            <i class="la la-clock-o"></i>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Testados</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;" id="total">0</span>
        </div>

        <div class="badge badge-info badge-pill" style="padding: 10px 10px;margin: 5px;">
            <i class="la la-cloud-upload"></i>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;"> Carregados</span>
            <span style="font-size: 15px;" id="carregadas">0</span>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="text-center text-light mt-3">
            <h4 class="text-light" id="status_ccs">AGUARDANDO INICIO...</h4>
        </div>
    </center>

    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 p-0">
        <div class="card bg-dark text-light">
            <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;">
                <button id="mostra" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px 5px;"><i class="la la-external-link-square" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 style="font-weight: bold;" class="card-title text-light">Aprovados - <span  id="cLive2" class="badge badge-success">0</span></h6>
                <div id="bode"><span id=".aprovadas" class="aprovadas"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 p-0">
        <div class="card bg-dark text-light">
            <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;">
                <button id="mostra2" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 2px 5px;"><i class="la la-external-link-square" style="font-size: 30px;"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 style="font-weight: bold;" class="card-title text-light">Reprovados - <span  id="cDie2" class="badge badge-danger">0</span></h6>
                <div id="bode2"><span id=".reprovadas" class="reprovadas"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    

</div>
    <!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="theme-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN VENDOR JS-->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE VENDOR JS-->
    <script src="theme-assets/vendors/js/charts/chartist.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE VENDOR JS-->
    <!-- BEGIN CHAMELEON  JS-->
    <script src="theme-assets/js/core/app-menu-lite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="theme-assets/js/core/app-lite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END CHAMELEON  JS-->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS-->
    <script src="theme-assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#bode").hide();
            $("#esconde").show();
            $('#mostra').click(function(){$("#bode").slideToggle();});
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#bode2").hide();
            $("#esconde2").show();
            $('#mostra2').click(function(){$("#bode2").slideToggle();});
        });

   

    function enviar() {
    var linha = $("#lista").val();
    var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
    var total = linhaenviar.length;

    if (total > 500) {
        alert("Limite: 500 GERADEX POR TESTE!");
        return;
    }

    var ap = 0;
    var rp = 0;
    $('#testar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#parar').attr('disabled', null);


    var callBackFn = function(index) {
        if (index >= linhaenviar.length) {
            return;
        }
        var value = linhaenviar[index];

        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: 'afa.php?lista=' + value,
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            success: function(resultado) {
                if (resultado.match("APROVADO")) {
                    removelinha();
                    ap++;
                    aprovadas(resultado + "");
                    $('#status_ccs').html('APROVADO');
                } else {
                    removelinha();
                    rp++;
                    reprovadas(resultado + "");
                    $('#status_ccs').html('');
                }
                $('#carregadas').html(total);
                var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                $('#cLive').html(ap);
                $('#cDie').html(rp);
                $('#total').html(fila);
                $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                $('#cDie2').html(rp);

                if (fila == total) {
                    $('#testar').attr('disabled', null);
                    $('#parar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#lista').attr('disabled', null);
                    // audio.play();
                    document.getElementById("status_ccs").innerHTML = "FINALIZADO";
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById("status_ccs").innerHTML = "AGUARDANDO INICIO...";
                    }, 6000);
                }
                index++;
                callBackFn(index);
            }
        });
        $('#parar').click(function() {
            ajaxCall.abort();
            $('#testar').attr('disabled', null);
            $('#parar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#lista').attr('disabled', null);
            var st = 'PAUSADO';
            $('#status_ccs').html(st);
        });
    }


    callBackFn(0);

}
            });
        }
        function aprovadas(str) {
            $(".aprovadas").prepend(str + "<br>");
        }
        function reprovadas(str) {
            $(".reprovadas").prepend(str + "<br>");
        }
        function removelinha() {
            var lines = $("#lista").val().split('\n');
            lines.splice(0, 1);
            $("#lista").val(lines.join("\n"));
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Expected Result:

I need only another call to be made in the API after the end of the later one and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your enviar function so that each ajaxCall is executed just after previous has finished.

Notice:
I created a variable "callBackFn". This is function that will be used as callback.
At the end of ajax success I executed this callBackFn.

```
function enviar() {
    var linha = $("#lista").val();
    var linhaenviar = linha.split("\n");
    var total = linhaenviar.length;

    if (total > 500) {
        alert("Limite: 500 GERADEX POR TESTE!");
        return;
    }

    var ap = 0;
    var rp = 0;
    $('#testar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#parar').attr('disabled', null);


    var callBackFn = function(index) {
        if (index >= linhaenviar.length) {
            return;
        }
        var value = linhaenviar[index];

        var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url: 'afa.php?lista=' + value,
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            success: function(resultado) {
                if (resultado.match("APROVADO")) {
                    removelinha();
                    ap++;
                    aprovadas(resultado + "");
                    $('#status_ccs').html('APROVADO');
                } else {
                    removelinha();
                    rp++;
                    reprovadas(resultado + "");
                    $('#status_ccs').html('');
                }
                $('#carregadas').html(total);
                var fila = parseInt(ap) + parseInt(rp);
                $('#cLive').html(ap);
                $('#cDie').html(rp);
                $('#total').html(fila);
                $('#cLive2').html(ap);
                $('#cDie2').html(rp);

                if (fila == total) {
                    $('#testar').attr('disabled', null);
                    $('#parar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#lista').attr('disabled', null);
                    // audio.play();
                    document.getElementById("status_ccs").innerHTML = "FINALIZADO";
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById("status_ccs").innerHTML = "AGUARDANDO INICIO...";
                    }, 6000);
                }
                index++;
                callBackFn(index);
            }
        });
        $('#parar').click(function() {
            ajaxCall.abort();
            $('#testar').attr('disabled', null);
            $('#parar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#lista').attr('disabled', null);
            var st = 'PAUSADO';
            $('#status_ccs').html(st);
        });
    }


    callBackFn(0);
}
```

By the way, if you intend to process audio I would suggest using https://howlerjs.com/

Comment: I need that only another call is made in the API after the end of the later one and so on.

Comment: enviar function makes sequential ajax calls. After one have success it's finished then next one is started. If it's not what you wanted, please give example what do you expect.

Comment: And that is what I want to edit the question with the code of its function, more when trying to press the button "start" it does not answer.

Comment: I wanted you to check if I entered the code correctly.

Comment: There is syntax error in your edited code.
You have 3 unnecessary brackets "});}" after enviar function.
Line 202 and 203.

Comment: Missing brackets isn't always easy to find. If you have no IDE that checks for syntax errors then you can use online tool https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html